# Custom Windows Authentication Blazor Returning AppPool

Tags: c#, authentication, iis, .net-core, blazor

For my Blazor application, I am using a custom authentication state provider. What it does by default, is grab the users Windows credentials and grants authorization that way. If they are denied access, they are presented with a login screen to login with their credentials. Example is the following:

```
            if (UseWindowsAuthentication)
            {
                var currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
                Login = currentUser.Name;
                if (currentUser.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var identity = await GetAuthorization();
                    user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    LoggedIn = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                    //custom login implementation
            }
```

This works fine when I run it on my local machine but when ran on the server, instead of grabbing the windows identity, it grabs the app pool like such:  IIS APPPOOL\App

What settings do I need to tweak in order to get this working? I have looked into this and I do see that there are impersonation options but I'm not sure how to include that in this server Blazor app.

Is there any additional code I can add/change to get this working hosted on the server? Any insight would be greatly appreciated... thanks!

Comment: You need to enable `Windows Authentication` and disable `Anonymous Authentication` in IIS Authentication section. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/) for further information.

Comment: `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();` of course gives you the pool identity. Very basic facts, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-basic-facts-about-iis-asp-net-process-thread-identities-835eaac876a0

Comment: @LexLi thank you for the reply...I understand now why it's failing but I'm trying to figure out how to solve the problem to get the actual user level information in my Blazor server app once it's hosted.

Comment: If you do read my post carefully, you should know that by querying the thread identity you might get what you wanted.

Comment: Have you tried System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name or 

 HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name. I can get the real user identity instead of app pool name in IIS.

Comment: @JokiesDing thanks for the reply! I did try HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name and it gave me the name on the first authentication check but on the second pass, it returned null. I did this by registering HttpContextAccessor in the startup service and injecting IHttpContextAccessor in my custom authentication provider. I did not try the other method though. That might be worth a shot. I will let you know how it goes... thanks!